# Pixel Painting Grid?

Tags: objective-c, macos, grid, export, paint

How can I create, for my Mac application, a grid, which then I can paint into each cell, each cell representing a pixel which I can then translate into a graphic and export.

I am specifically interested in the grid painting part at the moment.